# HTML/JavaScript: Dynamically hide a set of td / tr based on other variable and cell value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a purely front-end "application" for a game. (HTML, JS & CSS).
I will have an element holding the current points (pts) and another holding the current location (`currentLocation`). Additionally, I have a table holding the distance between two locations.

```
        |London|New York|LA
London  |0     |100     |200
New York|100   |0       |50
LA      |200   |50      |0
```

I now would like to:

- A: only show the column, which matches the location set in the input
  element (`currentLocation`)
- B: only show the row, in which the value of the cell is larger than
  the input element (pts)

Assuming `currentLocation = London and pts= 200`, I'd like to get:

```
New York | 100
LA | 200
```

Assuming `currentLocation = London and pts= 100`, I'd like to get:

```
New York | 100
```

What would be the best design to achieve this? I was thinking to include spans with a specific class per column to achieve **A**. However, I do not know how to achieve **B**

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us what you have tried in either a snippet or a JsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I've currently built the html structure but the question. I was hoping that I'd get some input on the design pattern I could use before I start with assigning classes/ids and JS coding.

Comment: Whatever you do keep the class attribute for CSS and the ID attribute for scripts. As I understand your question is that you want to look up stored values. Where do you store these values? If you store them in a database like MSSQL then you should consider ASP or PHP to get the values with T-SQL language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description
I have no idea how you store your distance table

So I assume your data store in locations, use the code below：

```
function getDistance(currentLocation, pts) {
  const locations = {
    'London': [{ pts: 0, location: 'London' }, { pts: 100, location: 'New York' }, { pts: 200, location: 'LA' }],
    'New York': [{ pts: 100, location: 'London' }, { pts: 0, location: 'New York' }, { pts: 50, location: 'LA' }],
    'LA': [{ pts: 200, location: 'London' }, { pts: 50, location: 'New York' }, { pts: 0, location: 'LA' }],
  };
  const result = locations[currentLocation].filter(item => item.pts <= pts && item.pts !== 0)
  console.log(result)
}

getDistance('London', 200);
getDistance('London', 100);
```

and the result will like this:

```
[ { pts: 100, location: 'New York' },
  { pts: 200, location: 'LA' } ]
[ { pts: 100, location: 'New York' } ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Storing them in an array and then dynamically building the innerHTML from the result of the filter seems to be more suitable than hiding/showing column as I originally planned. I'll go further with that option.